# Using the biblatex styles in the CTAN contrib

Tags: biblatex

I know how to use `biblatex` and compile it with `pdflatex` -> `bibtex` -> `pdflatex` in TeXworks or TeXShop.

```
\usepackage[options]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bib-file}

\begin{document}
  \autocite{einstein01}
  \autocite{feynman47}
\end{document}
```

How do I start using the different biblatex styles in the [CTAN contrib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/)? I want to know how to do it in terms of:

1. Installation
2. Usage in the source code

Solutions for MiKTeX or TeX Live are preferred.

Comment: This doesn't really need to be another answer but it's worth mentioning in this context: read the documentation for the style! For example, `biblatex-apa` needs you to put a `\DeclareLanguageMapping` after you load biblatex. I can't be the only person tripped up by this...

Comment: @Seamus: Thanks. I was looking at `biblatex-science`, and there was no documentation as how to use it.

Comment: it looks like `biblatex-science` is maintained by @Joseph Wright so he's the man to talk to about that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most of the CTAN biblatex styles are part of TeXLive, so if you update all the packages using tlmgr (or TeXLive Utility on a Mac), they should be available automatically.

Generally the styles are called by

```
\usepackage[style=<name>]{biblatex}
```

or with separate bib and cite styles:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=..., citestyle=...]
```

You can use `texdoc` to find the documentation for how to use the particular styles.

If in the unlikely event that the style you want isn't part of TeXLive, you can install extra biblatex packages into the latex folder of your local texmf folder just like you would install any other latex package. It's helpful to keep them in separate folders (or even in one biblatex folder within the latex folder.)

If you put the documentation into a folder corresponding to the style name in the local texmf/doc/ folder it will also be found with `texdoc`.

Answer (score 9):

As Alan says, many of the contributed styles are available in TeX Live and MiKTeX. If not, the style files themselves (`.bbx` and `.cbx`) need to be installed like any other locally-installed files. Taking the example of my own [`biblatex-chem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chem) bundle, I'd need to create a local installation folder which is operating system dependent:

- `~/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-chem` on Linux (`~` = your home folder)
- `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-chem` on Mac OS X (`~` = your home folder)
- `<USERPROFILE>\texmf\tex\latex\biblatex-chem` on Windows (`<USERPROFILE>` = your home folder)

You might already find the `texmf` folder and some subfolders, or you might have to create it. You'd then put all of the `.bbx` and `/cbx` files from CTAN in this new folder. If you are using MiKTeX on Windows, you then need to make sure it has `<USERPROFILE>\texmf` set as a 'root' in the MiKTeX Options.

It is not necessary to subdivide the `biblatex-chem` folder into folders `bbx` and `cbx`, although you can if you like ([`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) itself does this).

Optionally, you might install the documentation files (PDFs, `.tex` and `.bib` sources) in `texmf/doc/latex/biblatex-chem`. However, that's only necessary if you want `texdoc biblatex-chem` to work.

For other `biblatex` styles, the same applies and all you need to do is modify the folder name.

Comment: on a Linux machine it can also be $TEXMFLOCAL instead of $TEXMFHOME

Comment: @Herbert. My take is usually that people asking for instructions on installation won't have moved stuff about. So I go with the standard settings exclusively. (Most newer users probably won't know what `$TEXMFHOME` is!)

Comment: @Joseph Just so I get this clear, there's no need to create either a biblatex folder or separate cbx, bbx, lbx folders; you can just install the folder for the style into your texmf/tex/latex folder just like you would install a regular package? (Then I should simplify the second part of my answer.)

Comment: @Alan: beyond `tex/latex`, organisation is 'up to you'. Using a per-package folder is the convention, but is not enforced by the `texhash` system. So you install `bbx` and `cbx` files in exactly the same way as a standard package.

Comment: Ok.  I'll adjust my answer. (I think I was assuming biblatex was sensitive to folder structure like the bib/bst structure that is required (and enforced.))

Comment: You could mention that on linux `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` will tell you where to put stuff...

Comment: or `echo $TEXMFHOME`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the full power of `biblatex` then you should also install the program `biber` which can be done by the TeXLive package manager (and MikTeX's as well). It can also be installed via 
http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/.

Running `biber` instead of `bibtex` with `(Any)tex->biber->(Any)tex` gives you full UTF support for the bibliography, which isn't possible with  `bibtex` or `bibtex8`.

Using `biber` needs a

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=...]{biblatex}
```

You should also consider, that `pdflatex` can handle only a subset of UTF-8. Only `XeTeX` or `LuaTeX` have full UTF support.

Comment: You can install `Biber` using the TLContrib repository for TeX Live 2010. See http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/ (which has the recent update to do better mapping of UTF-8 to LaTeX characters for pdfLaTeX).

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem with the limited UTF-8 support of `pdftex`. If the bibliography has an UTF8 character for which TeX has no command sequence then you are lost ...

Comment: I did say 'better': I was thinking of cases where LaTeX can handle things. It's still more convenient to be able to have a UTF-8 bibliography file. (This is what I do, where the only accents I need to worry about are `\"`, `\'`, _etc._, which LaTeX can handle but which I'd rather not hard-code into my database.) You are of course correct that for full UTF-8 abilities you need a UTF-8 engine.

Comment: @Joseph: it is not only the missing full UTF-8 support in `pdftex`, it is also a problem with the characters which are not supported by `inputenc`. And a LaTeX user didn't really know that the `biber` option `bblsafechars` helps here. The documentation of `biber` is a really short one.

Comment: MiKTeX does also include biber: http://miktex.org/packages/miktex-biber-bin